# HashMap и чтение из файла

Tags: java

Написать программу в которой можно из консоли 
делать текстовые записи в файл (с помощью Scanner)
в кодировке "cp1251".

Запись в файле должна отделяться от предыдущей,
например линией.

### Структура записи:

Дата и время когда сделана запись (должно добавляться автоматически)
Текст записи

Добавьте метод для считывания всего файла в кодировке "cp1251".
Этот метод должен записывать текстовый файл в коллекцию HashMap (словарь).
Ключом будет Дата и время записи, значением - Текст записи.
Вывести заполненную коллекцию HashMap в консоль.
Например, есть файл с такой записью:

> Tue Aug 20 21:54:53 EEST 2019
>
> ## Привет мир
>
> Tue Aug 20 21:55:13 EEST 2019
>
> ## Hello World
>
> Не получается сделать так, чтобы ключом была Дата. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "Cp1251");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String fileName = "Test.txt";
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream(fileName, true),
                        "Cp1251"
                )
        )) {
            bw.append(new Date().toString()).append(lineSeparator).append(str);
            bw.append(lineSeparator).append("=====================================================").append(lineSeparator);
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        reader();
    }

    public static void reader() {
        HashMap<Date, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Test.txt"),
                        "Cp1251")
        )) {
            String s;
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                hm.put(Date.from(Instant.EPOCH), s);
                System.out.println(s);
            }
           br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.*;    

public class Examp5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "Cp1251");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String fileName = "Test.txt";
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(fileName, true), "Cp1251"))) {
        bw.append(new Date().toString()).append(lineSeparator).append(str);
        bw.append(lineSeparator).append("==================").append(lineSeparator);
        bw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        reader();
    }

    public static void reader() {
        Map<String, String> hm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Test.txt"),
                    "Cp1251"))) {
        String time;
        String text;
        while ((time = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text = br.readLine();
            hm.put(time, text);
            String s = br.readLine();
            if(s.contains("======")) continue;
        }
        br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hm.entrySet()){         
            System.out.printf(
                "Time: %s  Text: %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
       }
   }
}
```

Насколько я понял из задания - нужно записывать в файл дату, на следующей строке текст и на третьей строке разделитель (==========). Затем считывать из файла и записывать ЭТО в мапу, ключ это дата (из этого файла!), а текст в значение. В твоём коде ты в файл пишешь правильно, а в мапу почему-то записываешь НОВУЮ дату, а не дату из файла:

```
m.put(Date.from(Instant.EPOCH), s);
```

насколько я понял, нужно именно строку даты из файла. И еще - я применил LinkedHashMap (может это и не важно) но так красивее, т.к. выводит элементы мапы в порядке как были в файле ))). Насчет алгоритма чтения из файла - там можно разными способами, читать по 3 строки, например, и записывать в мапу, заморочиться через "регулярки" и т.д. Главное чтобы работало.

Comment: Да, спасибо все верно, только подскажите что делает именно эта строка `if(s.contains("======")) continue;` и зачем мы еще раз заносим `String s = br.readLine();`

Comment: У нас файл разбит на одинаковые блоки по три строки, последняя из которых это разделитель "=====". В цикле мы последовательно читаем эти строки в разные переменные (я специально разбил что-б легче понять было), time записываем в ключ, text - в значение. Затем читаем третью строку - разделитель, проверяем её через .contains("==="). Т.е. если строка содержит в себе "===", то она нам не нужна, мы ее просто пропускаем, не пишем никуда и возвращаемся в начало цикла. Можно еще разными способами читать, о чем я писал выше, но я специально сделал похожим на твой код, чтобы понятнее было.

Comment: ага все понял спасибо)

Comment: В принципе, если проверка разделителя не нужна, то можно строки String s = br.readLine() и  if(s.contains("======")) сontinue  заменить на br.readLine(); Т.е. мы просто читаем третью строку "в никуда" (а мы знаем, что там точно разделитель) и переходим (перепрыгиваем) через неё. Но если нам нужна проверка разделителя, то я показал как. Может в файле будут разные разделители и в зависимости от этого нужно будет менять логику программы и т.д. Это я только для наглядности, что можно вести контроль хода чтения файла по разделителям и т.д.